# Convert T-SQL using IF to Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, t-sql

```
IF NULLIF(@date, '') IS NULL
select * from [dbo].[SRC_DSSI_OPER_STAT]
else
select * from [dbo].[SRC_DSSI_OPER_STAT] where CONVERT(DATE, (shift_start_date)) =  CONVERT(DATE, @date - 1)
```

How can i convert this T-sql code to PostgreSQL

Comment: Is this part of a stored procedure/function?

Comment: nope. I will convert it into just a script and i'll add a parameter

Comment: Plain SQL can not use variables like that in Postgres (or in most other DBMS). Although you can achieve a similar effect with `psql`  variables (but then the script will only work in the command line client `psql`).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing @date is a string, in postgresql I will call it **input_date**

```
IF input_date = '' THEN
    select * from "SRC_DSSI_OPER_STAT";
ELSE
    select * from "SRC_DSSI_OPER_STAT" where shift_start_date::date =  input_date - interval '1' day;
END IF;
```

You can have problems about your date format, in that case you must working more on date conversions.

Comment: You can't use an `IF` statement in Postgres outside of a stored function.

Comment: maybe you know how to call a stored function in c# using posgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right. I answered before your comment in the answer. Because questions says postgresql, and not SQL, I supposed it was in a stored.

Comment: @eirawn I don't understand. Call a function is just like a query: "SELECT * FROM mypostgresqlfunction(myparameters)";

Comment: so is there no other way?

Comment: Not this way, but try to expand your problem. Maybe there is another solution. For example, if you start from c# and need to call an sql statement, you can have the if in your c# code and compose the right SQL string.